# Save a date when a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to know how to get the first Date when the futures_price is higher that prices_df.  In this case I want 2022-05-05 because 2100 > 1082.77.  Once the condition is met I don't need to save more dates, so even though 2000 is also higher than 1074.52 I don't want to get '2022-05-06'.

```
prices_df = [1106, 1098, 1090.625, 1082.577, 1074.52]
future_dates = {'Date': ['2022-05-02', '2022-05-03', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-05', '2022-05-06'],
                'High': [1020, 1005, 966, 2100, 2000],
                }
future_prices = pd.DataFrame(future_dates)
future_prices = future_prices.set_index('Date')


df3.loc[i, 'Break_date'] = future_dates['Date'] if future dates > prices_df
```

This last line should save in df3, break_date column the previous date '2022-05-05'.  Only 1 date.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
future_prices.loc[future_prices['High'] > prices_df].index[0]
```

**Result**

```
'2022-05-05'
```

You would need to add additional error checking to handle the situation where the condition was not met.

**Handling the situation where the condition was not met**

```
msk = future_prices['High'] > prices_df
future_prices.loc[msk].index[0] if msk.any() else 0
```

`else 0` could be else **whatever** depending on your application.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer.  I'm using:  df3.loc[i, 'Break_date'] = future_dates.loc[future_dates['High'] > eee].index[0]   but returns this error:  result = self._data[key]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0.     do you know why?  If the condition is not met, how can I record a blank for instance?  Using ifs?

Comment: Right `if` would work.  I updated my answer to address.

Comment: Awesome, you nailed it.  thank you very much, is working as expected after hours of desperation :)